# Javafx Collision Detection inTimeLine

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-8, collision-detection

I am using timeline for animating lines but I can't detect collisions. 
Here is a short example of what I am trying to do basically.

```
    Line line = new Line(100, 200, 200, 200);
    Line line1= new Line(350,50,350,300);

    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.5), new KeyValue(line.endXProperty(), 400))
    );
    animation.setCycleCount(1);
    animation.play();

    if(line.getBoundsInParent().intersects(line1.getBoundsInParent())){
        System.out.println("Collision!");
    }

    Pane root = new Pane(line);
    root.getChildren().add(line1);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

I used some other codes,method,ideas that I found in stackoverflow. Like following one:

```
    Bounds bounds = line.getLayoutBounds();
    Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(line, line1);

    boolean intersects = intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1;

    System.out.println("Intersects: " + intersects);

    if(intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("This object can overlap other the other object!");
        System.out.print("Collision detected!");
    }
    else
    {
        intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        System.out.print("Collision not detected!");
    }
```

And some variaions of this code.

Any idea would help

Comment: What do you mean by "collision" here? That the line segments intersect? These lines will never intersect: the first is always left of `x=200` and the second is always right of `x=350`.

Comment: Yes, I mean intersect. Actually line is moving because of the animation. I executed it.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was misreading which line was being animated. Can't you just calculate the time at which they will intersect anyway? Seems like it would be basic geometry...

Comment: You only check the intersection before the animation is started. If you want to dynamically check, you need to add a listener to the properties that are adjusted during the animation and that the check depends on. (In this case the `boundsInParent` property.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the "collision" (first time the lines intersect) is when `line.endX` reaches 350.

So you can simply do:

```
    BooleanBinding intersecting = line.endXProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(350);
    intersecting.addListener((obs, wasIntersecting, isNowIntersecting) -> {
        System.out.println("Collision!");
    });
```

i.e.:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedLine extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line = new Line(100, 200, 200, 200);
        Line line1= new Line(350,50,350,300);

        BooleanBinding intersecting = line.endXProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(350);
        intersecting.addListener((obs, wasIntersecting, isNowIntersecting) -> {
            System.out.println("Collision!");
        });

        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.5), new KeyValue(line.endXProperty(), 400))
        );
        animation.setCycleCount(1);
        animation.play();


        Pane root = new Pane(line);
        root.getChildren().add(line1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In general, detecting whether or not two line segments intersect might be a little harder than the case where one is horizontal and one vertical, but you can always solve the equations pretty easily and do something similar to this.